# Scale option for external display not avaible in macOS Ventura?

Tags: macos, ventura

After upgarde to macOS 13.0 Ventura, the `scaled` option is gone for my external monitor.

The [help](https://support.apple.com/en-hk/guide/mac-help/mchl86d72b76/mac) on Apple official website did mention such an option:

[image]

However, it's not found on my Ventura Display setting screen:

[image]

How can I get the `scaled` feature back?

I do not see on the following option screen on My display ([screenshot source](https://medium.com/internetstack/how-to-set-a-custom-scaled-screen-resolution-on-macos-ventura-5751e185d2b5)):

[image]

Final note: I don't understand why the moderator of this forum insists the so-call duplicated question is answered. The *answer* to that question is a 3rd party application, which is not a macOS Ventura solution. If the moderator still does not see the difference, please checkout the last screenshot (in which, *some* macOS Ventura installations do have that option, built-in, no 3rd party app is needed.)

Comment: Are you unable to choose any of the other resolutions listed in the second screenshot for your external monitor? Any resolution that is not your external monitor’s native resolution would be `scaled`.

Comment: Those resolutions are extremely blurry on my 4K external display, compared with the scaled resolution in macOS 12.

Comment: What is your external display’s actual resolution and which resolution do you prefer to go with? Which of the resolutions listed in the screenshot have you tried?

Comment: My external monitor is 4K, any option in Ventura lower than 3840x2160 will result in a blurry screen. `scale` used to work, differently, it _looks like_ fewer pixel (everything is larger, scaled up) but it is still clear (at higest resolution).

Comment: The question is in the review queue for reopening already.

Comment: I too have this issue. Feel like I'm starting to go crazy. At one random moment it looked properly but now does not. I'm on an ultrawide display, and now all scaled resolutions are either wayy too big (low pixel count = everything is a street sign) or the native res, which is unusably tiny.

Comment: Having the same issue after an update. Pain.

Comment: From your source: "Note: This doesn’t seem to work for in-built MacBook screens, and for some external monitors that don’t support a custom scaled resolution."